# Intersection of line with cube and knowing the point of intersection

Tags: c#, vector, 3d

description

1. lines are originating from origin(0,0,0).
2. lines are at some random angle to the Normal of Top face of the cube.
3. if the lines are intersecting cube, calculate the intersection point.
4. mainly I want to know how much distance the line traveled inside the cube.

I don't know exactly which approach I should take, I would be pleased and thankful if someone could guide me to the right direction, to use OpenGL, DirectX or some other library, for C#.
Some example or sample will be appreciated.

Comment: Check out reply to previous question [Efficient maths algorithm to calculate intersections ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385305/efficient-maths-algorithm-to-calculate-intersections)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem involves the intersection of lines and a cube in 3D space. This is fundamentally a computational geometry problem, and it doesn't strictly require graphical libraries like OpenGL or DirectX.

There might be two intersection points (one where the line enters the cube and another where it exits). You'd have to calculate the distance between these two points to find the length of the line segment inside the cube.

As I already mentioned, if you only want to compute the intersection, you don't necessarily need a graphics library. There are libraries like MathNet.Numerics which can be helpful for mathematical computations.
If you want visualization, libraries like Helix Toolkit (which wraps around DirectX/OpenGL) can be handy. Unity3D is also an option if you're okay with a heavier framework.

In terms of concrete implementations in C#, you might not find a direct library or method that gives this out-of-the-box. You'd likely have to implement the core intersection logic yourself, but using a library can help with the overall management and visualization of 3D data.

Comment: Re the question you just deleted: I dropped your code into a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/) with a couple of reasonable guesses, and it worked just fine, updating the attribute on the button when the right values were picked from the dropdown. (I edited it into the question [ users with a certain rep level can see and edit deleted questions].) Thought you'd want to know. Perhaps observation error? HTH!