# LibGDX - BoundingBox and Ray intersection

Tags: collision-detection, libgdx, intersection

LibGDX has `Intersector` class which contains `intersectRayBoundsFast` function. I'd like to know how to use it? First of all how to bounding my airplane like below?:

[image]

The second question is how to properly move this `BoundingBox`? There is no such functions like `setPosition`, `rotate` and so on.
And the third one is how to create correct `Ray` object to find intersection between shell and airplane?

[image]

Help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

Generally bounding boxes are coarse tests.  For speed of testing, the bounding boxes are often "axis-aligned" (abbreviated "AABB"), specifically this means they don't rotate with an object, but resize as the contained object rotates.  (The images you included in the question are reasonable examples of an AABB for the airplane sprite.)

Bounding box intersection tests run quickly, so they can eliminate all the elements that are totally irrelevant, but leave you with a set of items that *might* be hit.  After that you can do (if necessary, and *its often not necessary*) a more precise intersection test.  For example, based on the underlying geometry or by using pixel-based ray intersection.  Note that pixel collision is [complicated in libGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=350).

For your specific case, I think you can model the airplane as line.  Imagine drawing a single line from the nose to the tail, if the shell hits that line, it hit the airplane.  You don't really need precise pixel-based collision detection (this approach will look good enough).

Assuming your shells are moving vertically, you just need to compute the intersection of two line segments: [Efficient maths algorithm to calculate intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385305/efficient-maths-algorithm-to-calculate-intersections)

All that said, you probably don't even need to be that precise and can get away with the coarse AABB based test.  For example, in the bottom image, while the shell isn't actually intersecting the plane yet, its clearly going to.  Assuming its moving fast enough, the player won't be able to tell.  You can fudge it a bit by making the bounding box a bit smaller (perhaps leaving a bit of the tail end of the box) if you want to make the game a bit eaiser or more forgiving.

Also, don't use the `Ray` for detecting intersection (that's for things like testing if a touch point is intersecting a box).  You should use an AABB for the shell, and do a [rectangle overlap test](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html).

Comment: I thought about making line from the nose to the tail. But it doesn't suit me if the shell go through the nose left of the bottom line. Of course I can create the second line which perpendicular the bottom line. But I really want to know how to use `Ray` and `BoundingBox` in example. But thanks anyway!