# Algorithm/Formula to create a Line/Bar that abides a set specifications out of a list of coordinates

Tags: javascript, svg, angle

at the moment i am having a problem i am sure someone else has faced and probably solved before me.  Sadly i dont know what to call this problem or which keywords to use to search for it. So far my research wasn't successful.

I would be thankful if you could point me in the right direction or help me find a solution that is simpler that my current one which i personally think to be too complex.

Language: Javascript
Objects: SVG-objects

The task:

Given is an array of coordinates which are symbolizing data points and a width. My objective is to generate line between the points that has the given width at all points. Also i have to be able to split the lines at the middle bewteen to neighbouring points. For a width of less than 3 or 4 pixels i can easily realize this by simply using a polyline. But if the width becomes bigger the polyline creates an growing error.

[Example 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM39L.png) - The little blue dots represent the original coordinates

The error is that the svg polyline extends itself over the coordinate to generate the tip of the corner. through this the exact representation of the information becomes faulty. My objective is to recalculate the coordinates so that the this extended tip of the corner lays exactly (1 pixel tolerance) on the given coordinate.

It is also possible to replace the line with a polygon oder construct it through multiple fomrs if that would be simpler.

In the end the result should look somehwat like [this masterpiece of paint-skills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB0IR.jpg) but filled and not just an outline.
Now the to spezifications:

- Start and end-points lay on the middle of the line (point 1 and 5)
- Angles wiht less than 90 degrees (point 2 and 3) are represented of the tip od the resulting tip (inner angle)
- Points with more than 90 degrees (point 4) should lay on the bisecting line of the angle

At the moment my solution is base on geometry, getting the angles form the values i know and then caclulating new points, but with its already very complex and complicated and i just fear it will take way to long  to get it to be as exact as i need it to be.

I think programms like photoshop or other vectoring tools are able to do something similar to my situation, but since i dont know how this problem/algorihtm is called i havent found much usefull information yet.

Thanks so much in advance folks!

Comment: sorry if that is not clear, im not asking you to give me the code, im asking for information about this kind of algorithm/problem. where and what to search for since i dont know what this problem is called or if someone knows, an idea (again not in code) how to calculate it myself

Comment: I understand the problem of not knowing what terms to search for. I don't know if there is a specific term for this problem either, but I'd start by searching for intersection algorithms, particularly intersections of sets of objects/lines.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/385305/2472391) concerning algorithms for fast calculations of intersections between line segments.

Otherwise, I would look for vector libraries like [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) or [SVG.JS](http://www.svgjs.com/) to see if they have anything you can use.

Final thoughts: with the example you gave, I suspect you will find Path elements to be the simplest solution. Also, you are concerned about the speed of naïve calculations, but I think that unless you are dealing with thousands and thousands of points, you will be surprised when you give it a try.